# How to use Assuming and With together

Tags: equation-solving, scoping, assumptions

(I am sorry for the ASCII form, I use the free WolframEngine which works in text mode.)

I have these assumptions `vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0 && bFx > bRx && t > 0`, this substitution (i.e. scope) `bRis = 100` and this equation `(1/2)*((- 1*aRx*(rho^2))+(-1*bRim*bRx*(rho^2))+(2*aRx*rho*t)+(2*bRim*bRx*rho*t)+(-1*bRim*bRx*(t^2))+(2*t*vR0))==bRis`. All values are real. I want to find the equation for `t`. Without the assumptions and the scoping,

```
Solve[(1/2)*((-1*aRx*(rho^2))+(-1*bRim*bRx*(rho^2))+(2*aRx*rho*t)+(2*bRim*bRx*rho*t)+(-1*bRim*bRx*(t^2))+(2*t*vR0))==bRis, t]
```

produces two solutions:

```
t = (aRx rho + bRim bRx rho + vR0 +- Sqrt[-2 bRim bRis bRx + aRx  rho  + aRx bRim bRx rho  + 2 aRx rho vR0 + 
 
                        2
2 bRim bRx rho vR0 + vR0 ]) / (bRim bRx)
```

I am not sure if both are correct, given the assumptions and the scope. This in turn, which lacks only the scope,

```
Assuming[vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0 && bFx > bRx && t > 0, Solve[(1/2)*((-1*aRx*(rho^2))+(-
1*bRim*bRx*(rho^2))+(2*aRx*rho*t)+(2*bRim*bRx*rho*t)+(-1*bRim*bRx*(t^2))+(2*t*vR0))==bRis, t]]
```

produces no solutions, which I would find surprising (increasing $\rho$ in the pair of solutions above should eventually assure that both the square root argument and $t$ are positive).

How to use at once assumptions (`Assumptions`?) and scope (`With`?) with `Solve` and limit the solution to the real domain?

Answer (score 1):

```
assumptions = 
  vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0 && 
   bFx > bRx && t > 0;
With[
 {bRis = 100},
 Assuming[
  assumptions, 
  Solve[(1/
       2)*((-1*aRx*(rho^2)) + (-1*bRim*bRx*(rho^2)) + (2*aRx*rho*
         t) + (2*bRim*bRx*rho*t) + (-1*bRim*bRx*(t^2)) + (2*t*vR0)) ==
     bRis, t, Reals]
  ]
 ]
```

Gives me

```
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[(aRx rho + bRim bRx rho + vR0)/(
     bRim bRx) - 
     Sqrt[-200 bRim bRx + aRx^2 rho^2 + aRx bRim bRx rho^2 + 
      2 aRx rho vR0 + 2 bRim bRx rho vR0 + vR0^2]/(
     bRx Abs[bRim]), (bFx > 
        bRx && (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0) < bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(
        bRx rho^2) && 100/vR0 < rho < 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && 
       aRx > (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && bRim > 0 && 
       rho < 100/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && aRx > (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 &&
        rho < 100/
        vR0 && (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0) < bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(
        bRx rho^2)) || (bFx > bRx && bRim > 0 && 
       rho > 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && bRim > 0 && 
       100/vR0 < rho < 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && rho < 100/vR0 && 
       aRx < (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && 
       0 < bRim < (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0)) || (bFx > bRx && 
       rho < 100/vR0 && aRx < (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && 
       bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(bRx rho^2))]}, {t -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(aRx rho + bRim bRx rho + vR0)/(bRim bRx) + 
     Sqrt[-200 bRim bRx + aRx^2 rho^2 + aRx bRim bRx rho^2 + 
      2 aRx rho vR0 + 2 bRim bRx rho vR0 + vR0^2]/(
     bRx Abs[bRim]), (bFx > bRx && 
       rho > 200/vR0 && (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(bRx rho^2) < bRim < 
        0) || (bFx > bRx && (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(bRx rho^2) < bRim < 
        0 && 100/vR0 < rho < 200/vR0) || (bFx > 
        bRx && (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0) < bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(
        bRx rho^2) && 100/vR0 < rho < 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && 
       aRx > (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && bRim > 0 && 
       rho < 100/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && aRx > (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 &&
        rho < 100/vR0 && (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(bRx rho^2) < bRim < 
        0) || (bFx > bRx && aRx > (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && 
       rho < 100/
        vR0 && (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0) < bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(
        bRx rho^2)) || (bFx > bRx && bRim > 0 && 
       rho > 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && bRim > 0 && 
       100/vR0 < rho < 200/vR0) || (bFx > bRx && rho < 100/vR0 && 
       aRx < (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && 
       0 < bRim < (-aRx^2 rho^2 - 2 aRx rho vR0 - vR0^2)/(-200 bRx + 
         aRx bRx rho^2 + 2 bRx rho vR0)) || (bFx > bRx && 
       rho < 100/vR0 && 
       aRx < (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(
        bRx rho^2) < bRim < 0) || (bFx > bRx && rho < 100/vR0 && 
       aRx < (200 - 2 rho vR0)/rho^2 && 
       bRim < (-200 - aRx rho^2)/(bRx rho^2))]
```

Comment: I added to the question the two solutions obtained without the assumptions and the scope. I would guess (only guess) that adding the assumptions and scope would remove one of these two, and not produce something much more complex.

Comment: Is there meant to be a restriction on `bRim` ?

Comment: I analysed the solution in your answer and it is in fact the same thing, only that there are some long conditions on the sign in front of the square root. I will try to add some additional assumptions to see if these conditions can be avoided.

Comment: It can be assumed for simplicity that 0 < `bRim` < 1.

Comment: Also, max time can be limited `t<=((bRx^-1)*((bRit*bRx)+(-1*bRim*bRit*bRx)+(aRx*rho)+(bRx*rho)+vR0))`

Comment: The assumptions do not seem to be working. One of them is `bFx > bRx` but it repeats in the solution as a part of a condition.